# Remove download, share, autoplay button from lightGallery

Tags: lightgallery

I've been trying to removes these button for a few hours and couldn't get it to work. Following is what I have so far.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
      lightGallery(document.getElementById("lightgallery"), {
        selector: '.tilter',
        download: false,
        share: false
      });
    </script>
```

```html
          <div id="lightgallery" class="col-12 col-xl-9 col-xxl-12">
                <div class="row row-15 row-md-30 gutters-10 gutters-md-30" data-lightgallery="group">
                  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="tilter"><a class="figure-classic" href="/images/sport-1.jpg" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="/images/sport-1.thumb.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="300"></a></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="tilter"><a class="figure-classic" href="/images/sport-2.jpg" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="/images/sport-2.thumb.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="300"></a></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="tilter"><a class="figure-classic" href="/images/sport-3.jpg" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="/images/sport-3.thumb.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="300"></a></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="tilter"><a class="figure-classic" href="/images/sport-4.jpg" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="/images/sport-4.thumb.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="300"></a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
  lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'),{
    share: false,
    autoplayControls: false,
    download: false
  });
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).